# Adding Salesforce Mobile SDK to Ionic App not working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to add Salesforce mobile SDK to my existing Ionic V2 hybrid App, but the command stops as below without any result forever. I waited for more than 10 mins max. Any help will be great.
I have Cordova 7.1.0 installed

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue here. The problem was with `Cordova version - 7.1.0` which doesn't support saleforce mobile sdk plugin properly. I downgraded the cordova version to `6.4.0` and tried to add the mobile sdk plugin, it worked fine.